Coloring regions between lines with Tikz

How can I create something similar to this figure in TikZ, coloring the regions between the lines?
Start code:
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\clip (0,0) circle (4);
\draw (-5,-2) -- (5,-2);
\draw (1,-6) -- (1,6);
\draw (2,-6) -- (2,6);
\draw (-5,0) -- (3,-3);
\draw (-4,-4) -- (3,3);
\draw (3,-3) -- (0,12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You nee to create a MWE where you show the lines and the circle.

Adding the code for the lines.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
closedLines/.style={
to path={(\tikztostart) -| ([shift={(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)}]current bounding box.south west) -- ([shift={(\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)}]current bounding box.south east) |- (\tikztotarget) -- cycle},
},
inverseFill/.style={
insert path={([shift={(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle ([shift={(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)}]current bounding box.north east)}
},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=4];
\draw[fill=lightgray, even odd rule, thick, closedLines, inverseFill]
%leftmost coordinate must be placed left in list below
 (-5,-2) to (5,-2)
 (1,-6) to (1,6)
 (2,-6) to (2,6)
 (-5,0) to (3,-3)
 (-4,-4) to (3,3)
 (0,12) to (3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much! I wasn’t familiar with the 'Even-Odd Parity Rule.'

I could not find a good way to automatic sort/use the leftmost coordinate, so the lines need to be specified with the leftmost coordinate(lowest x-value) before to.
